# Rotating Dates Logic in Salesforce using Configuration

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I am working on a requirement where I have to achieve the 'Shifting of dates' logic in one of my Custom Objects.

The requirement is-

```
Custom Object 'Obj' of 3 fields - 
Start Date
End Date
Period
```

The 'Period' is always 90 days.

Whenever a record is created-

```
1. Start Date - TODAY()
2. End Date - TODAY() + Period (Today + 90 Days)
```

What I want to achieve is, whenever the 90 days period is over, (TODAY() == End Date), the 'Start Date' and 'End Date' are again shifted to the next 90 day period.

eg-
Start Date - 1st Jan
End Date - 30th March

on 30th of March, the Start Date should be set to '30th March', and End Date should be set to '30 March + 90 days'.

This should be continuous.

Currently,

I am using 2 time based workflows to achieve this.

```
WF 1- Marks a flag (isEndDate) on Obj to TRUE when TODAY() == END DATE
WF 2- Whenever 'isEndDate' == TRUE, 
START DATE == TODAY, END DATE == TODAY + 90, and isEndDate == FALSE.
I have marked the 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change' to TRUE on this field update.
```

However, I have to look at this as the last feasible solution as I don't want any additional WFs triggering to the 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change' option.

Is there a better way to achieve this via configuration?

Thanks!